# How to listen to mouse hold event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know `mousedown` is when user press the mouse, `mouseup` is when user release the mouse. But I want to listen the event after user press the mouse and hold it until it release. Any ideas?

Comment: Listen for both, if the mousedown event is called but not mouseup, then the user is holding the mouse.

Comment: how can I continually doing something during mouse holding?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want the **hold** state then it will be the state when you are in `mousedown` event state for a while. This state exists when you press `mousedown` but not `mouseup`. Hence you need to take a variable which records the current state of the event.

**jQuery**

```
$('div').on('mousedown mouseup', function mouseState(e) {
    if (e.type == "mousedown") {
        //code triggers on hold
        console.log("hold");
    }
});
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LCnUw/4/)**

Comment: There's no need for the ternary - `==` always returns a boolean.

Comment: @AkinHwan please elaborate. better to post a new question and share the link if you think I can help you.

Comment: Hi Mr_Green, specifically I was trying to change my working code that used pointerevents with mouse events api since that seems cross browser supported. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56463451/workaround-for-safari-ios-pointer-events-not-supported

Comment: Is there a way to code this in plain JavaScript? I can't find how to translate `.on('mousedown mouseup'`.

Comment: @LukoFoks you have to write separately for both events using `addEventListener`

Comment: This will trigger on every mouse click, better place a debounce to capture hold state.

Answer (score 5):

```js
var setint  = '';
$(document).ready(function() {
var val = 0;
$('#hold').on('mousedown',function (e) {
   clearInterval(setint);
   val = 0;
   setint = setInterval(function () {
       $("#putdata").val(++val);
        console.log("mousehold");
   },50);
});
$('#hold').on("mouseleave mouseup", function () {
   val = 0;
   $("#putdata").val(val);
   clearInterval(setint);
});
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="putdata" />
<input type="button" value="mouse-hold" id="hold" />
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: I'm building a web-based d-pad for a servo controller and this is exactly what I needed to see how long the up/down/left/right was being held.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

Add respective mouse events to folowing functions

```
mouse = false;
function mousedown()
{
  mouse = true;
  callEvent();
}
function mouseup()
{
  mouse =false;
}
function callEvent()
{
 if(mouse)
 {
   // do whatever you want
   // it will continue executing until mouse is not released


   setTimeout("callEvent()",1);
 }
 else
 return;
}
```

Comment: This is very dangers (bug potential) solution. If the user release the mouse button outside the window (browser) the `mouseup` event will not fire and your method: callEvent will run in a loop forever.

Comment: @GilEpshtain i have just shown how to tackle asked problem, i think OP knows which event listeners(mouse down, mouse up, mouse out) needs to be added. If all event listeners added properly then there will not be any issue.

Answer (score 2):

From jquery.com :

HTML :

```
<p>Press mouse and release here.</p>
```

Script:

```
$("p").mouseup(function(){
    $(this).append('<span style="color:#F00;">Mouse up.</span>');
}).mousedown(function(){
    $(this).append('<span style="color:#00F;">Mouse down.</span>');
});
```

Full url : http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/

Answer (score 1):

Use setInterval() to keep executing your code when until the mouse is down and use clearInterval() to stop the setInterval() function when the mouse is released.

```js
var id;
window.onmousedown = () => {
    console.log(“holding..”)//Since setInterval doesn’t start
    //immediately and causes clearInterval to execute first

    id=setInterval(()=>{
        console.log("holding...")
    },300)
}
window.onmouseup = () => {
    clearInterval(id)
    console.log("released...")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

logic to ignore the click and get the hold only, in above mentioned answer by Sumit, a check can be added to ignore the click and listen to only the hold:

```
var id;
var check = null;
  

window.onmousedown = () => {
      //Since setInterval doesn’t start
      //immediately and causes clearInterval to execute first
    check = null;
      id=setInterval(()=>{
          if(check == null)
          console.log("holding...")
      },300)
  }

  window.onmouseup = () => {
      clearInterval(id)
      id = null;
      check = 1;
      console.log("released...")
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it in vanilla JavaScript to simulate mouse hold event.

```js
let mouseHoldTimer;
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(function (btn) {
  btn.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
      //clear any existing timer
      clearTimeout(mouseHoldTimer);
      
      mouseHoldTimer = setTimeout(function () {
          //create and dispatch a unique custom event for each element
          var holdEvent = new Event('mousehold');
          btn.dispatchEvent(holdEvent);
          console.log('held', btn.innerHTML);
      }, 500); // adjust the duration as needed
  });

  btn.addEventListener('mouseup', function (e) {
      //clear the timer when the mouse is released
      clearTimeout(mouseHoldTimer);
  });
});
```

```html
<button>button1</button>
<button>button2</button>
```