# Workaround for Safari IOS pointer events (not supported)

Tags: javascript, browser, safari, cross-browser

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/pointerdown_event

Hello I have working code for a long click, but pointer event api is not supported in Safari only, currently under development.

Is there some simple workaround I can apply just for safari? Unless I can just use some other event? I've tried with 'mousedown/mouseup' but no luck.

The below code works with "touchstart/touchend" as well as "pointerdown/pointerup" but neither have comprehensive browser support.

```
    let pressTimer;
    this.myDocsums.on('touchend', () => {
      clearTimeout(pressTimer);
    }).on('touchstart', (e) => {
      let startY = window.pageYOffset;
      let docsum = $(e.currentTarget);
      let selectorInput = docsum.find('.selector-input');
      pressTimer = window.setTimeout(() => {
        let endY = window.pageYOffset;
        if (startY == endY) {
          selectorInput.trigger('click');
        }
      }, 750)
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Safari now supports pointer events (PC: 2019/09/19, Mobile: 2019/10/28).

Comment: For this purpose and in this context, no it doesn't; https://caniuse.com/?search=pointerup